# Join 3 tables with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following tables:

```
Products
prod_id  |  prod_name  |  prod_price


Supermarket
supermarket_id  |  name  |  address


supermarket_product
supermarket_id | product_id
```

How can I join those tables to get a table that shows all the information from Products and Supermarket tables in 1 single big table? I am basically trying to have a table only to hold which product belongs to which supermarket based on it.

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT prod_name, prod_price, supermarkets.name 
FROM products 
INNER JOIN supermarkets 
    ON supermarket_product.supermarket_id = supermarket.supermarket_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join products and supermarkets through bridge table `supermarket_product`:

```
select p.*, s.*
from products p
inner join supermarket_product sp on sp.product_id = p.prod_id
inner join supermarket s on s.supermarket_id = sp.supermarket_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to also include `supermarket_products` in the query. You should also use table aliases to simplify your code:

```
SELECT p.prod_name, p.prod_price, s.name 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN supermarket_product sp ON sp.product_id = p.prod_id
INNER JOIN supermarket s on s.supermarket_id = sp.supermarket_id
```